# Rails: Problems installing Jcrop plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, plugins, path, head

I'm new to web development, so I'm sorry if this is basic stuff. I'm not sure how to connect the code in my application.html.erb or crop.hmtl.erb to the actual files I downloaded. Specifically, I downloaded the files for Jquery UI and Jcrop(which is reliant on Jquery UI) and moved both of them into my application's vendor file (home/website/vendor). I then followed a Jcrop tutorial to install the plugin,but it doesn't work. I think my application isn't successfuly accessing one or both of the downloaded files. The Jcrop guide gave me a suggestion for what to put in my application.html.erb but said I might have to adjust the code according the actual paths. I don't know how to do this or even what to look up to research it. Can anyone help?

Application.html.erb: this is what the Jquery UI guide `(http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/)` told me to put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is what the Jcrop guide `(http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html)` suggested I put into my application.html.erb, but said I may have to adjust:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
```

crop.html.erb

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
  $("#cropbox").Jcrop();
});
</script>
<% end %>

<%= image_tag @thing.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asset files (such as Javascript and CSS) should go in their respective folders inside of `app/assets`. For instance, if you place your files at the following locations within your application:

```
assets/javascripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js
assets/stylesheets/jquery.Jcrop.css
```

You can then reference these files within your `application.html.erb` file (or crop.html.erb, using content_for) using the rails asset helpers:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
```

Additionally, there is a [jcrop-rails-v2](https://github.com/maxd/jcrop-rails-v2) which may make the inclusion of JCrop assets easier.

Comment: So I can use "<%= stylesheet_link_tag..." in place of "<script src=..."?

Comment: Correct. The `stylesheet_link_tag` method generates that script tag for you with the supplied arguments. If you want to insert inline javascript, then use the `<script>` tag as you are currently doing.